# Firestore rule to check the value of a dynamic field within a map

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Think of a poll app, which has a map in a Firestore document.
This map has the vote key as string and a number as value (counter).
For instance “what is the best food”:

```
{
...
...
poll : [
    pizza : 10,
    barbecue: 3,
    pasta: 1,
    ...
     ]
...
}
```

The items can vary depending on the poll. Only one vote per user. Only logged in users can vote (Firestore rule).
The minimum amount is zero, people can switch from one to another (decrease moment).
Also, the increase should be only +1.

Transactions protect the app to avoid less than 0 for any item and +1 is controlled there.
Is there a way to protect also with the Firestore rules?
To be honest, I’m not sure if it’s necessary.

I can get the affected items with map diff functions. But how do I check for that specific changed item value?
The map diff result brings a set, however I cannot use the keys retrieved by the set in the `request.resource.data`, otherwise the problem would be solved.
I could check whether it’s 0 and also check with current data if the difference is 1.

The key will be in the map for sure, since it comes from the diff function from the map itself.

Answer (score 0):

Update Feb 2021: this doesn't work for the latest firebase since the keys are  a set which can't be indexed

You can get the affected keys using

```
let affectedKeys = request.resource.data.poll.diff(resource.data.poll).affectedKeys();
```

However according to the [firebase docs on MapDiff](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) it's not possible to get the changes in values, only in keys.

If you know how many poll items there are, you can do something like

```
let differenceOfOne = request.resource.data.poll[affectedKeys[0]] == resource.data.poll[affectedKeys[0]] + 1 || request.resource.data.poll[affectedKeys[0]] == resource.data.poll[affectedKeys[0]] - 1
```

and repeat that line for every index up to the maximum number of items (loops are not allowed in firebase rules).

Comment: Does this still work for you? Based on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#affectedKeys), `affectedKeys` returns a `rules.Set` which doesn't allow accessing with an integer index. I did try to do the same thing with something like `affectedKeys[0]` above but it raises an error `Invalid type. Received one of [set]. Expected one of [string, list, map, path]` when compiling rules.

Comment: I just tried and it looks like you're right, this doesn't work anymore :( haven't been able to find alternative solutions yet

Comment: You can submit a feature request here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features
I already submitted mine, but you can support this request.